# JavaScript map and match array of objects with object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with this structure:

```
[
    {
        "ticker": "SPR",
        "isExcluded": false,
    },
    {
        "ticker": "K",
        "isExcluded": false,
    },
    {
        "ticker": "TR:CA",
        "isExcluded": false,
    },
    {
        "ticker": "TEL:CA",
        "isExcluded": true,
    }
]
```

And an object of objects with this structure:

```
{
    "K": {
        "ticker": "K",
        "weight": 19.15
    },
    "SPR": {
        "ticker": "SPR",
        "weight": 34.55
    },
    "TEL:CA": {
        "ticker": "TEL:CA",
        "weight": 30.61
    },
    "TR:CA": {
        "ticker": "TR:CA",
        "weight": 15.69
    }
}
```

I would like to return the object of objects with the corresponding isExcluded value for each ticker added after its weight.

The expected output is adding the isExcluded value to the object as such:

```
{
    "K": {
        "ticker": "K",
        "weight": 19.15,
        "isExcluded": false
    },
    "SPR": {
        "ticker": "SPR",
        "weight": 34.55
        "isExcluded": false
    },
    "TEL:CA": {
        "ticker": "TEL:CA",
        "weight": 30.61,
        "isExcluded": true
    },
    "TR:CA": {
        "ticker": "TR:CA",
        "weight": 15.69,
        "isExcluded": false
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?
Your help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi. Can you share what you've tried so far by adding your code to the question as a [mcve]?

Comment: Could you please add an expected output as well and on which condition you are trying to implement generation of new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const object = { K: { ticker: "K", weight: 19.15 }, SPR: { ticker: "SPR", weight: 34.55 }, "TEL:CA": { ticker: "TEL:CA", weight: 30.61 }, "TR:CA": { ticker: "TR:CA", weight: 15.69 } };

const arr = [{ ticker: "SPR", isExcluded: false }, { ticker: "K", isExcluded: false }, { ticker: "TR:CA", isExcluded: false }, { ticker: "TEL:CA", isExcluded: true }];

const output = Object.values(object).reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr.ticker] = {
    ...curr,
    isExcluded: arr.find((arrObj) => arrObj.ticker === curr.ticker)?.isExcluded,
  };
  return prev;
}, {});
console.log(output)
```

another way would be to mutate the original object like so:

```js
const object = { K: { ticker: "K", weight: 19.15 }, SPR: { ticker: "SPR", weight: 34.55 }, "TEL:CA": { ticker: "TEL:CA", weight: 30.61 }, "TR:CA": { ticker: "TR:CA", weight: 15.69 } };

const arr = [{ ticker: "SPR", isExcluded: false }, { ticker: "K", isExcluded: false }, { ticker: "TR:CA", isExcluded: false }, { ticker: "TEL:CA", isExcluded: true }];


Object.values(object).forEach(
  (obj) =>
    (obj.isExcluded = arr.find(
      (arrObj) => arrObj.ticker === obj.ticker
    )?.isExcluded)
);
console.log(object)
```

Comment: Could you please explain you code, I really find it hard many times to understanding what's going on here I have seen many question on stack but could not understand how this ```filter```,```map```,```reduce``` works with complex data.

Comment: Thank you @jacob-stephenson , these solutions are amazing and worked perfectly. I would just add that the "?" isn't needed and will cause an error. ✨Again, thanks for making my day. These were driving me crazy.

Comment: @MelanieSigrid No problem, and the ? `?.isExcluded)` is Optional Chaining, which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: @jacob-stephenson Oh thanks for the update! That was awesome. Thanks for the explanation and both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

u can use array of objects becuz u need to store same types of data in a array.and u can get access to them with index like this(if u sorted the same in both arrays)

```
firstArray[3]=   {
        "ticker": "TEL:CA",
        "isExcluded": true,
    };
secondeArray[3]= {
        "ticker": "TEL:CA",
        "weight": 30.61
    }
i
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately the array and object will definitely be sorted in different order. Because this result is used in multiple parts of my program, I need to keep the structure and do need to return the object of objects, just add the isExcluded value that I'm getting from the array.